# wagtail admin interface on django project

Tags: django, templates, wagtail

please anybody have idea on how to use the wagtail admin interface for my project instead of the usual django admin interface.  i have tried installing wagtail as part of the project but django default admin interface is what my project is using. Or suggestions on how to overide the default django admin template will be helpful to me thanks

Comment: all i need is a little push in the right direction.

Comment: What do your URL Patterns look like? Maybe the Wagtail docs can help you point the /admin in the proper direction. http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v0.8.7/howto/settings.html#url-patterns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html for details of integrating Wagtail into an existing project - in particular, note the "URL configuration" section, which explains how to make the Wagtail admin backend available at the URL `/admin/` or any other URL of your choosing.

Wagtail is not intended to be a drop-in replacement for the Django admin - you will have to re-implement the configuration logic to actually make your models visible within Wagtail. The ModelAdmin module is the closest equivalent to Django admin: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html

Comment: Ok let me  check it out i will post what works. Thanks for the effort!